# Ajax request pending when run on async

Tags: ajax, laravel, asynchronous, axios

i have a page that make 10 - 20 ajax request to load data from background. But as i look in mozilla developer tools network status, even all request is shown, processed request still run in fifo

you can see my network status screenshot 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kswGB.jpg)

fyi, this is internal request and not cross-platform request and i use laravel 5.5 for application and axios to make ajax request

is this kind of flow (request executed in fifo order) is normal in async request?
or maybe i need to set something in my web server?

Thanks

Comment: Usually browsers limit the ajax requests to the same server to 3 (or 5 maybe not sure) concurrent requests. You can get around this limit by using multiple domain aliases for your server or using http/2.

Comment: as my request is result from a loop, looks like option 1 (multiple domain) maybe not applicable, and for option 2 (http/2) is this applicable in https too?

Comment: Browsers will only use HTTP/2 if it's over HTTPS so HTTP/2 is **only** applicable to HTTPS